# What data structure(s) should I use to map three "old" values to three "new" values?

Tags: c#, data-structures, mapping

I'm trying to figure out what sort of data structure would make sense to represent my data. I'm working on a C# tool that will update the names of a specific set of Categories, SubCategories, and SubSubCategories. Here is some example data:

```
OldCategory | OldSubCategory | OldSubSubCategory | NewCategory           | NewSubCategory | NewSubSubCategory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware    | Display        | Broken            | HD-Hardware           | Display        |
Hardware    | Display        | Request upgrade   | Requests              | Hardware       | Display 
Software    | Excel          | Error message     | HD-Software           | Excel          | General Error
Software    | Excel          | How Do I          | HD-Software           | Excel          | Training
Software    | Excel          | Plug-in           | HD-SoftwareExtensions | Excel          |
```

As you can see, I cannot simply update every `OldCategory` to a corresponding `NewCategory`. The data is built so that each combination of `Category`, `SubCategory`, and `SubSubCategory` is a unique value. For example, `Hardware | Display | Request upgrade` will be mapped to `Requests | Hardware | Display`.

How do I map the combination of the three old values to the combination of the three new values?

I was considering using a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string, string>, Tuple<string, string, string>>` structure, but that seems awfully verbose and potentially confusing to other developers or my future self. Any suggestions for a clearer representation of my data?

Comment: Why not just create a class and use objects?

Comment: Can you add an example transformation?

Comment: @Bedir I could. Do you think that makes sense in given the context in my question and compared to a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string, string>, Tuple<string, string, string>>`?

Comment: @stuartd This is for our Help Desk ticketing system. I'm interacting with an API and the categories are properties of a ticket. So a ticket with the three "old" category values needs to be changed to have the three "new" category values. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It is a bit verbose, indeed... but I don’t see any other direct and reliable solution other that building a custom object that, in the end, is most likely to be even worst than what you came up with in the first place.

Comment: Ah, so `Hardware|Display|Request upgrade` maps to `Requests|Hardware|Display` and `Hardware|Display|Broken` maps to HD-Hardware|Display`?

Comment: @stuartd Correct.

Comment: And what kind of update is this? SQL? Or is it some kind of translation layer? In other words, what's getting changed?

Comment: @stuartd I'm interacting with a Help Desk ticketing system API. I'm getting a list of all Tickets, and if they have a specific combination of Category, SubCategory, and SubSubCategory, the ticket needs to be updated to the new Category, SubCategory, and SubSubCategory combination. The API wraps the ticketing system's database. I don't have direct access to that database.

Comment: Using a `Dictionary<3-tuple,3-tuple>` just seems wrong to me.  I suspect that using a more fleshed out version of @Bedir's answer and a `Dictionary<Category, Category>` would be easier to understand, debug and monitor.

Comment: @Flydog57 I agree that it seems wrong. That's why I asked the question :) Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I've been talking about in the comments:

```
public class Category : IEquatable<Category>
{
    public string MainCategory { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string SubSubCategory { get; set; }


    private string GetCharacterizer()
    {
        return $"{MainCategory}#{SubCategory}#{SubSubCategory}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetCharacterizer().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Category other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return GetCharacterizer().Equals(other.GetCharacterizer());
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is Category catOther))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals(catOther);
    }
}
```

Then you'd create a `Dictionary<Category, Category>`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is a more complete answer so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Disregard my last (now deleted) comment. I was being an idiot :)

Comment: @LewsTherin: You may also want to implement the `==` and `!=` operators (you must do both if you do one).  But, since you have `Equals`, that's easy.  Also, write some tests, this is _whipped together quickly_ code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going the same route that you are speculating i.e.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string, string>, Tuple<string, string, string>>
```

With the new `ValueTuple`, you can use a more concise syntax to do this

```
var tbl = new Dictionary<(string, string, string), (string, string, string)>();
var newVal = tbl[("Hardware", "Display", "Request upgrade")];
```

You can also use names for the Tuple Fields like below

```
var tbl = new Dictionary<(string Cat, string SubCat, string SubSubCat), (string Cat, string SubCat, string SubSubCat)>();
```

If you need more flexibility, control or features, you can use a class for this like below

```
class CatInfo : Tuple<string, string, string> {
    public string Category => Item1;
    public string SubCategory => Item2;
    public string SubSubCategory => Item3;

    public CatInfo(string cat, string subCat, string subSubCat) : base(cat, subCat, subSubCat) { }
}
```

If for whatever reason, you cannot subclass from `Tuple`, or want a slightly better performance, then you can just create a immutable struct like below

```
struct CatInfo {
    public string Category { get; }
    public string SubCategory { get; } 
    public string SubSubCatergory { get; }

    public CatInfo(string cat, string subCat, string subSubCat) {
        Category = cat;
        SubCategory = subCat;
        SubSubCatergory = subSubCat;
    }

    public bool Equals(CatInfo other) {
        return string.Equals(Category, other.Category) && string.Equals(SubCategory, other.SubCategory) && string.Equals(SubSubCatergory, other.SubSubCatergory);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj is null)
            return false;
        return obj is CatInfo info && Equals(info);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        unchecked {
            int hashCode = (Category != null ? Category.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (SubCategory != null ? SubCategory.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (SubSubCatergory != null ? SubSubCatergory.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CatInfo info1, CatInfo info2) {
        return info1.Equals(info2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CatInfo info1, CatInfo info2) {
        return !(info1 == info2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a class seems like the best option to me. That way you can create a constructor, and have methods.
E.g.

```
public CategoryClass{
    string category;
    string subCategory;
    string subSubCategory;
}
```

And then you can put those in a dictionary:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CategoryClass oldCategory = new CategoryClass();
    CategoryClass newCategory = new CategoryClass();
    Dictionary<CategoryClass, CategoryClass> dict = new Dictionary<CategoryClass, CategoryClass>();
}
```

... or another object.

Comment: If you are going to do this, you are going to want to implement GetHashKey on the class (for example, by hashing some concatenation of the strings).  You are going to want to use this as a dictionary key.

Comment: I think this is the way I'm going to proceed (wrapping the categories in a class and then set up the mapping with a `Dictionary<ClassName, ClassName>`). It seems much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: And don't forget, GetHashKey and the other requirements to make a reference type act like a _Value_ (I don't remember them all, but Equals, etc.)

Comment: @Flydog57 Can you provide an example of how you would do that? I can only find [`Object.GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2) and that returns an `int`.

Comment: Also, you might want to change those to public properties rather than private fields

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/ for GetHashCode.The easiest way to do this is to create a private function that, for example concatenates the three strings with a separator and use it for equality, to get the Hash code (just take the hash code of the concatenated strings), etc.  And, I found what I was looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type